# How to search a pattern from a list and make a new list

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to search a pattern in a list coming from the service and make a new list with items found .
Here is my code.

```
 itemList = itemService.getList();
```

the itemList contains the following json data.

```
   [
      {
      "emailId": "jhonson@test.com",
      "Id": "100",
      "itemCode":       {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "item"
      },      
      "description": "item 100 description",
      "sendingId": "scott@test.com"      
   },
      {
     "emailId": "ketter@test.com",
      "Id": "101",
      "itemCode":       {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "item"
      },      
      "description": "item 101 description",
      "sendingId": "baker@test.com"  
   },
      {
      "emailId": "paul@test.com",
      "Id": "102",
      "itemCode":       {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "item"
      },      
      "description": "item 102 description",
      "sendingId": "wanda@test.com"  
   },
      {
      "emailId": "wendy@test.com",
      "Id": "103",
      "itemCode":       {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "item"
      },      
      "description": "item 103 description",
      "sendingId": "reil@test.com"  
   },
      {
     "emailId": "bee@test.com",
      "Id": "104",
      "itemCode":       {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "item"
      },      
      "description": "item 104 description",
      "sendingId": "dan@test.com"  
   },
      {
      "emailId": "michael@test.com",
      "Id": "105",
      "itemCode":       {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "item"
      },      
      "description": "item 105 description",
      "sendingId": "kris@test.com"  
   }
]
```

now I am trying to search a pattern from this list and make a new list.

```
searcPattern='jhonson' then the filterList should have these values.
   {
      "emailId": "jhonson@test.com",
      "Id": "100",
      "itemCode":       {
         "id": "1",
         "name": "item"
      },      
      "description": "item 100 description",
      "sendingId": "scott@test.com"      
   }
```

How to do this using filter in a controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
var filteredList = $filter('filter')(itemList , 'jhonson');
```

It will return a filtered list based on the array and expression you give.

In order to be able to use $filter, you will also need to inject it inside your controller :

```
function myCtrl($scope, $filter)
{
}
```

More information [HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: it worked for me.var filteredList =[];filteredList = $filter('filter')(itemList , 'jhonson'); but when I am trying to delete items from this list ,it still showing the deleted items.I used filteredList.splice(index,1) where index=currentIndex like 1,2,0r 3. can we use spilce when working with filters?

Comment: Sure you can. But $filter creates a whole new array so if it's a display problem you might want to work on your 'itemList ' array instead.

Comment: after apply filter on itemlist, I am displaying all filtered items,when selected a particluar item trying to delete.how can achieve this with filteredList?

Comment: I am unsure of what you want to achieve. Splice can delete an item if that's what you want, and does return the deleted item. How do you display the filtered list?

Comment: first I am getting the list from service.it is displaying in a view I have a textbox .if user eneter a search then I am displaying filteredlist in a view.In view, I am doing some actions like delete.if I select an item and click delete , I am calling splice. the splice worked well before I use filter but now I am using filter ,keeping filtered list displayed in a view,and when call filteredList.splice it is still showing in the view.but in console the filteredlist does not have deleteditem.